# Remove any line containing "X" amount of digits

Tags: notepad++

This is a strange one for me, iam quite good with Notepad++

but was lost as to how i can remove a line containing a certain amount of digits

i want to remove any line containing less than 10 digits:

from this:

```
1234567890
123456890
1234567890
12345890
```

to this

```
1234567890
1234567890
```

Comment: I don't know Notepad++, and I'm sure this question doesn't belong here, but the regex you want is `^[0-9]{,9}$`.

Comment: @Yossarian [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), is a free source code editor with a lot of functionality including RegEx find-and-replace, a function shared with many other code editors.

Answer (score 0):

Regex search-and-replace: Search for `^\d{0,9}$`, replace with empty space.

Comment: hmm `^\d{,9}$` is not working for me, and yes its set to regular expression before you ask :)